# Jade, mixins and extend

Tags: node.js, pug, extend

Given the following

```
/layouts
   main.jade
/partials
   some.jade
index.jade
```

Code in **main.jade**

```
html
    head
        title Layout page
    body
        block content
```

Code in **some.jade**

```
mixin list( title )
    h1 title
    ul
        li foo
        li bar
        li baz
```

Code in **index.jade**

```
extend ./layouts/main
extend ./partials/some
block content
    h1 Hello world
    +list( 'Ciao mondo' )
```

I'd like to know if there's some way to do something similar to this but that run without problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing

```
extend ./layouts/main
extend ./partials/some
block content
    h1 Hello world
    +list( 'Ciao mondo' )
```

with

```
extend ./layouts/main
include ./partials/some  //note this line!
block content
    h1 Hello world
    +list( 'Ciao mondo' )
```